# How to select all XPATH's of any website in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the product listings from any website. Some websites for example: Amazon, Alibaba have max 10 products on the page while some have 20. I don't want to put for loops in XPATH of each and every website.

Is there a way to get all the XPATH's related to a special attribute of any website? For example, if we have a XPATH of table, then it will show all the XPATH's of the table. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: ```xpath_to_element//*``` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Does it selects all XPATH's of the related attribute? For example if I select a XPATH of one question asked on stack overflow then will it allow me to get all the XPATH's of asked questions? If yes then can you please send me the code about how it works... @Mukesh

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need. Also this is unrelated to python (XPath is its own language). With XPath you select an element (or elements). You need to know the element by name (and, to some extent, the overall structure of the XML you're treating) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the example HTML I will use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYsyH.png)

*XPath of < ul> tag:*

- /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul

**XPaths of < li> tags:**

1. /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]
2. /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]
3. /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]
4. /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]
5. /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]

What you can do is make a more general XPath that will grab all of the XPaths you want.

*So say you want to find all the elements in the list:*

- /html/body/div[4]/div/aside[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li

Notice there is no [#] at the end of that XPath, so it will find all elements containing that xpath

**An example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.livesoccertv.com/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr')
print(len(test))
driver.close()
```

This returns a result of 35